# PHP - Sort multi-dimensional array of number arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
$arr = [
    [4,6],
    [1,2,3],
    [7,8,9] 
];
```

I'd like to sort it so the result is

```
$arr = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,6],
    [7,8,9] 
];
```

If I apply `sort($arr)`, it first sorts by array length and then compares the values. So I get

```
$arr = [
    [4,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [1,2,3],
];
```

which is wrong for my purposes.

I could use a sorting algorithm to compare the elements.

Or I could create another array with each element imploded and then sort it.

But was wondering if there was an inbuilt or quicker way of getting this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsort()` to get the order you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks, but rsort() will not work if I have [7,8,9]. My testcase is too perfect, so I will update it.